# Apply rule if no items in a set match a certain form?

Tags: kframework

I would like to apply a rule:

```
rule <k> __BETA__ => __PROCESS__ </k>
     <processes> S:Set </processes>
```

If `S` contains no items of the form `SetItem( new X . P )` or `SetItem( P | Q )`.

I read in the manual that a `:=` and `:/=` pattern-matching operator exists, but there's no example of its usage, and I don't know if it is what I need.

I remember seeing that K has no negative pattern matching for Sets, but is there a few to achieve the equivalent with the `:/=` operator maybe?

Incidentally, is K able to match and modify two items of a set at once? I tried the rule:

```
  rule <k> __PROCESS__ => __BETA__ </k>
       <processes> 
         ... 
         ( SetItem( A:KVar < B:KVar > . P:Process ) => SetItem( P ) )
         ( SetItem( A:KVar [ X:KVar ] . Q:Process ) => SetItem( Q[B/X] ) )
         ... 
       </processes>
```

but the semantics gets stuck. Is this valid syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have to see your semantics to give better advice, but it looks to me like you're trying to use the `Set` collection to store a bunch of processes, and each process has it's own algebraic term representing the current process state.

In that case, I would recommend using K's Cell multiplicity feature instead of storing it in a `Set`, pattern matching will work better there. I don't know for sure, but it's possible we don't support the Set pattern match you're attempting here. If you can make a minimal example of it, please submit an issue to https://github.com/kframework/k and we get make it supported.

Using K's cell multiplicity will definitely work though, you can do something like this:

```
    configuration <k> $PGM:Pgm </k>
                  <processes>
                    <process multiplicity="*" type="Set"> .Process </process>
                  </processes>

  rule <k> __PROCESS__ => __BETA__ </k>
       <processes>
         <process> A:KVar < B:KVar > . P:Process ) => P      </process>
         <process> A:KVar [ X:KVar ] . Q:Process ) => Q[B/X] </process>
         ...
       </processes>
```

In order to say that something should happen when none of the other patterns are matched by a process, I would recommend an `owise` rule:

```
    rule <k> __BETA__ => __DO_SOMETHING__ </k>
         <process> new X . P </process>

    rule <k> __BETA__ => __DO_SOMETHING__ </k>
         <process> P | Q </process>

    rule <k> __BETA__ => __DO_SOMETHING_DIFFERENT__ </k> [owise]
```

If you must keep it a `Set` for some other reason, it's still possible to use the `[owise]` rule approach. Alternatively, if you don't like the `[owise]` approach, you'll likely need a function which tells you whether there are any processes that meet your criteria.

For example, using the K multiplicity approach:

```
    rule <k> __BETA__ => __DO_SOMETHING__ </k>
         <processes> PROCESSES </processes>
      requires shouldDoSomething?(<processes> PROCESSES </processes>)

    rule <k> __BETA__ => __DO_SOMETHING_DIFFERENT__ </k>
         <processes> PROCESSES </processes>
      requires notBool shouldDoSomething?(<processes> PROCESSES </processes>)

    syntax Bool ::= shouldDoSomething? ( ProcessesCell ) [function]

    rule shouldDoSomething?( _ ) => false [owise]
    rule shouldDoSomething?( <processes> <process> new X . P </process> ... </processes> ) => true
    rule shouldDoSomething?( <processes> <process> P | Q     </process> ... </processes> ) => true
```

You can do the same thing using the `Set` approach, just define `shouldDoSomething?(_)` over the `Set` sort instead of over the `ProcessesCell` sort. Admittedly, I'm still using an `owise` in the definition of `shouldDoSomething?(_)`, but you can avoid it by explicitly enumerating all potential patterns and recursively removing processes which don't meet the criteria from the set until you get to the empty bag:

```
    rule shouldDoSomething?( <processes> .Bag </processes> ) => false
    rule shouldDoSomething?( <processes> (<process> P ; Q </process> => .Bag) ... </processes>
    rule shouldDoSomething?( <processes> <process> new X . P </process> ... </processes> ) => true
    rule shouldDoSomething?( <processes> <process> P | Q     </process> ... </processes> ) => true
```

In this example, you can see that I'm removing all processes that have `P ; Q` from the bag of processes, but if I find one that is either `new X . P` or `P | Q`, I'm saying `true`, and if we get to the empty bag of processes (so none of them were `new X . P` or `P | Q`) then we say `false`.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer! the examples are good. Would `.Bag => <process> P </process>` be the syntax to add new processes? Also, is it the case that something like `priority(100)` to perform a rule last be how `owise` works? if so, when using the `--search` option, the `owise` rule wouldn't be taken as a branch if other options are available, right? lastly, about Sets, what kind of items should we be using Set for?

Comment: Yes, that is how you would add a new process. The `owise` rule is actually like `priority(200)`. The `--search` option should make sure the `owise` rule if the other rules cover _all_ potential behaviors at that moment, but if it cannot prove it then it must also explore the `owise` branch (this is on _haskell_ backed, _java_ backend does not treat `owise` correctly). This is a good use for `Set`, but K Cell Multiplicity is probably a better tool for what you want in terms of pattern matching and making the rules readable.

Comment: How does the Java backend currently handle `owise`? Also, in the rules above, are `...` dots not necessary before the `process` cells? i.e. `<processes>...<process> P </process>...</processes>`?

Comment: Sorry to keep adding to the comment, but I have another question on usage. I have the rule:
`rule <k> __BETA__ </k>
       <processes>
         ...
         <process> P:Process | Q:Process => P </process>
         (.Bag => <process> Q </process>)
         ...
       </processes> `
and it is getting stuck on things of the form `P | Q`. Why is this? Is the syntax I'm using incorrect?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think the Java backend does not handle `owise` on `function` rules, but handles it correctly on non-`function` rules. It however does _not_ respect the `priority` attribute at all.

Comment: I think your approach with splitting processes looks correct, so I'm not sure why it's not working. You could do instead `rule <k> (. => newProcess(P)) ~> __BETA__ </k> <processes> ... </process> P | Q => Q </process> ... </processes>` and another rule `rule <k> newProcess(P) => . ... </k> <processes> ... (.Bag => <process> P </process>) ... </processes>` to emulate the same behavior.

Comment: Ah, thanks! I found that It's apparently an issue with brackets in the java backend. Apparently, I needed to put `<process> P:Process | Q:Process => P </process>` in parentheses or the pattern matching fails for some reason.

Comment: Ah yes, if you don't declare parentheses to be a `bracket` production, they will be treated as an actual constructor. To make them `bracket` production, you would do something like `syntax Process ::= "(" Process ")" [bracket]`, which tells the parser to not even construct an AST node for the parentheses.